# Call express middlewares next() inside a promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bluebird

I am trying to build a parameter middleware that loads a requested `object`
and appends it to the `request object`, so that I don't have to write the same code over and over again.
I am using `Sequelize` as an ORM to access a MySQL Database, which is Promise based (`bluebird`).
The code is as follows:

```
router.param('id', function (req, res, next, id) {
  return models.Object.findById(id)
    .then((object) => {
      //Check if the requested object was found
      if (object) {
        //Append the request object to the request object
        //for further usage in upcoming route handlers
        req.object = object
        return next()
      } else {
        //Throw an error, so that it can be caught
        //by the catch block of the promise chain
        let err = new Error('Object not found.')
        err.status = 404
        throw err
      }
    })
    //Catch any error and forward it to the
    //next express error handler
    .catch((err) => { return next(err) })
})
```

As you can see I am checking whether the requested object exists and if it exists, I append it to the request object of express. If not I am throwing an error.
When I am running this code I get the warning:
`Warning: a promise was created in a handler at /*path goes here*/ but was not returned from it`.
At this point I don't really know how to get rid of that error.

### Edit:

I tried the Solution of Hosar but unfortunately the warning still occurs. Here is the exact code I am using:

```
router.param('aId', function (req, res, next, aId) {
  models.Authorization.findById(aId)
    .then((authorization) => {
      if (authorization) {
        req.authorization = authorization
        next()
      } else {
        let err = new Error('Not Found')
        err.status = 404
        next(err)
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => { return next(err) })
})
```

The error occurs on the line where I want to call next() without any parameters.
The complete warning is:
`(node:5504) Warning: a promise was created in a handler at C:\Users\dkaiser
\repos\lead\lead_backend\routes\auth.js:10:16 but was not returned from it`

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you are returning a promise. Just avoid the first **return** you have. 
Try:

```
router.param('id', function (req, res, next, id) {
  models.Object.findById(id)
    .then((object) => {
      //Check if the requested object was found
      if (object) {
        //Append the request object to the request object
        //for further usage in upcoming route handlers
        req.object = object
        next()
      } else {
        //Throw an error, so that it can be caught
        //by the catch block of the promise chain
        let err = new Error('Object not found.')
        err.status = 404
        next(err);
      }
    })
    //Catch any error and forward it to the
    //next express error handler
    .catch((err) => { next(err) })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract data directly from a resolved Promise using an async middleware function from Node v7.6

```
router.param('id', async function (req, res, next, id) {
  const object = await models.Object.findById(id);
  if (object) {
    req.object = object;
    next();
  } else {
    let err = new Error('Object not found.')
    err.status = 404
    next(err);
  }
 });
```